# SqlServer error HY000: Partial insert/update while calling SQLPutData with an object with more than 400 KB in field of varbinary(max)

Tags: sql-server, blob, odbc

I have a big problem when I try to save an object that's bigger than 400KB in a varbinary(max) column, calling ODBC from C++.

Here's my basic workflow of calling SqlPrepare, SQLBindParameter, SQLExecute, SQLPutData (the last one various times):

**SqlPrepare**:
StatementHandle 0x019141f0
StatementText   "UPDATE DT460 SET DI024543 = ?, DI024541 = ?, DI024542 = ? WHERE DI006397 = ? AND DI008098 = ?"
TextLength      93

Binding of first parameter (BLOB field):
**SQLBindParameter**:
StatementHandle 0x019141f0
ParameterNumber 1
InputOutputType 1
ValueType       -2 (SQL_C_BINARY)
ParameterType   -4 (SQL_LONGVARBINARY)
ColumnSize      427078
DecimalDigits   0
ParameterValPtr 1
BufferLength    4
StrLenOrIndPtr  -427178 (result of SQL_LEN_DATA_AT_EXEC(427078))

**SQLExecute**:
StatementHandle 0x019141f0

Attempt to save blob in chunks of 32K by calling SQLPutData a number of times:
**SQLPutData**:
StatementHandle 0x019141f0
DataPtr         address of a std::vector with 32768 chars
StrLen_or_Ind   32768

During the very first SQLPutData-operation with the first 32KB of data, I get the following SQL Server error:
*[HY000][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Warning: Partial insert/update. The insert/update of a text or image column(s) did not succeed.*
This happens always when I try to save an object with a size of more than 400KB. Saving something that's smaller than 400KB works just fine.
I found out the critical parameter is ColumSize of SQLBindParemter. The parameter StrLenOrIndPtr during SQLBindParameter can have lower values (like 32K),
it still results in the same error.
But according to SQL Server API, I don't see why this should be problematic as long as I call SQLPutData with chunks of data that are smaller than 32KB.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I just found out this was actually an sql driver problem!
After installing the newest version of Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client (from http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=29065), saving bigger BLOBs works with exactly these parameters from above.